# Add Icon button in App bar of tab bar in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, appbar

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPLE4.png

I need to add iconbutton appbar flutter

Comment: just like in the picture

Comment: Can you specify which button you want to add? Is it the hamburger (menu) button or the plus sign (+) button?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean leading iconButton in appBar You can add this code in your scaffold

```
appBar:AppBar(leading:IconButton(icon:Icon(Icons.menu),onPressed:(){})),
```